# Why was std::swap moved to <utility>?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, swap

Why has `std::swap` been moved to the `<utility>` header for C++11?

N3290 C.2.7 says:

> 17.6.3.2
>
> Effect on original feature: Function swap moved to a different header
>
> Rationale: **Remove dependency on `<algorithm>`for swap.**
>
> Effect on original feature: Valid C++ 2003 code that has been compiled expecting swap to be in `<algorithm>` may have to instead include `<utility>`.

I can't understand the part in bold. What kind of dependency is being talked about and why?

Comment: That isn't actually the section number, the paragraph you cited is found in section C.2.7.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The committee wanted to allow you to use `swap()` without introducing a compile-time dependency on the large and more complex `<algorithm>` header file. Because `swap()` is so widely used, it makes sense to let you pull in its definition with as little additional baggage as possible; this will generally lead to faster compile times for files that don't otherwise need `<algorithm>`. Its new home allows it to be used without introducing unneeded overhead.

Comment: All nice and good for Linux based systems, but Microsoft waits years before implementing C++ standards (maybe even this one?).